# How many hours would a 38000 mAh powerbank will last?

Tags: battery-charging, amperage, batteries

i bought a 38000 mAh powerbank and to my surprise when I could only use it for a total of 6 hours and then I have to recharge it again. My battery's capacitu is 1 700 mAh. By the way I'm taking up education major in biosci, so I'm not really expert with this. PLS. HELP. THanks.

Comment: Search on this site, there are dozens of questions dealing with how to calculate how long some battery lasts.

Comment: Shocking as it may seem, some manufacturers have been known to overstate the actual capacity of their batteries, sometimes by a factor of 3 or 4:1.

Comment: What happens is that a manufacturer quotes the mAh rating of the internal battery, not accounting for the difference in voltage (battery vs. powerbank output) and convertion losses. In practice the Ah rating tells you ... nothing. Look for the Wh rating, that is usually more reliable. You should draw your conclusions when a Wh rating is not specified.

Comment: Any powerbank above about 10,000 mAh claimed should be treated with suspicion. It's possible but not likely. 38000 mAh is about 12 top class 18650 cells. Minimum area would be about 250mm x 70mm x 20mm. LiPO may be somewhat more comp[act but that;s still a VERY big VERY heavy power bank.

Answer (score 5):

As Plasma says in a comment this site is overflowing with calculations about batteries and warnings about power banks (some of which my own posts), I'm in a procrastinatory mood, because I have an algorithmic task that needs to back-of-mind bubble, so I shall rehash the important stuff.

---

That would depend on many factors:

1. Is it a main-brand 38000mAh, or a cheap eBay/Amazon third party at a fistful of dollars?
2. What device you connect
3. How they rated the power (linked to 1 in many ways).

Fist, 1: If it's eBay/Amazon-Third-Party there's no guarantee it's actually storing 38000mAh in any respect. Might be half, might be a quarter, might be even less. Might also be more, by the way, happened to me. Luck of the draw I guess.

Second, the device you connect draws a certain amount of power. This is not directly to do with your internal battery. Some devices have a 2000mAh battery inside, but will happily pull 2A continuously on the cable as well, when in active use.

Third and most imporantly, they often use 38000mAh on the internal battery. If they use normal Lithium Ion, that's a median voltage of 3.7V. mAh for a storage device with a constant voltage output with the intend of delivering a given amount of power is a stupid indication. It's why many laptop batteries quote Wh instead, because it is chemistry independent.

So assuming it's LiIon, it will be about `38Ah * 3.7V =~ 140Wh`.

But that's its *internal battery*

The outward voltage is regulated with electronics, which in the case of an A-brand may reach upto 95% efficiency for 5V output, or upto 90% efficiency for higher voltages.
B-brand (eBay and/or Amazon-third-party sales) may be as low as 80% efficient in either case or ***even lower***.

Let's assume 80%. That leaves only `0.8*140Wh =~ 112Wh`.

Then if you take this out at 5V that is about: `112Wh / 5V =~ 22Ah`.

So if that is drained in 6 hours, the device should be taking an approximate: `22Ah / 6h =~ 3.75A`. Which is very high for a 5V device, but not absolutely unheard of. But still, more likely that you actually did buy a B-brand and it's only half of what is advertised, in which case I can only say: You get what you pay for, or in this case, not what you didn't pay for.

If you are using a laptop-type device at 19V or similar on the bank, then it will only be draining: `112Wh / 19V =~ 5.9Ah` --> `5.9Ah / 6h =~ 0.99A`. Which in turn is very low for a 19V-ish device such as a laptop or similar, in which case I'd say you probably got what you ordered.

((Note: All intermediary numbers are rounded in the post, but not on my calculator, so if you get different results from just typing the last equation in a series: Use your Memory Store key between steps.))